# Querying - Get the highest value with length of value in "id"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

How to get the maximum value of id with length of 4 digits.

```
+--------+--------+
| id     | LName  | 
+--------+--------+
| 1234   |    ONE | 
| 123456 |    TWO |  
| 123    |  THREE |  
| 1239   |   FOUR |  
| 1233   |   FIVE |  
+--------+--------+

SELECT row 
FROM table 
WHERE id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM table
    )
```

How to get the maximum value of id with length of 4 digits.

Comment: Id ID a number or a string? If it's a string, how do you want to order: numeric value or lexicographic order? Also, do you need only to get ID or even the values in the other columns?

Comment: And if ID is a number, what type of number? if it can be a non integer, do you want to restrict the search to integer numbers with 4 digits or to all numbers with 4 digits, 0.123 for example?

Answer (score 3):

```
select max(id) from table where ((id > 999) AND (id < 10000));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select max(id) from t1 where id between 1000 and 9999;
```

check here [on sqlfiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d26039/2)

Comment: 4 digits, you probably mean `between 1000 and 9999`

Comment: @Aleksej yaa thanx for suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 4 methods

```
select max(id) from table where id >= 1000 AND id <= 9999;

select id from table where id >= 1000 AND id <= 9999 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,1;

select max(id) from table where length(id) = 4;

select id from table where length(id) = 4 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,1;
```

you can check performance (compared execute time). My suggestion is the first

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM table 
    WHERE LENGTH(id) = 4
);
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.